# Fedora 14 freezes while starting system logger

Tags: linux, filesystems, fedora, boot, repair

I'm having trouble starting Fedora 14 on my computer. The startup procedure freezes while `starting system logger`.

Before this started happening, I had formatted one of my logical disk partitions which is supposed to be mounted under the `/var` directory. I think may be the cause of this problem. However, I don't know how to fix it, as I can't get into the Linux command line to do a `umount`.

I don't have a CD with which to repair the system, so is there any way to fix this problem without one?

Comment: *GASP*. If you don't have a CD, then you need to get one **ASAP**. They are much more useful then they would appear at first glance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get in to make changes without needing a recovery CD. At the GRUB menu, press `e` to edit.  On the kernel line, append `S` to the end (space and capital 'S') and then enter to continue booting.  This will boot into single-user mode.  From there, you can modify any configuration files necessary to get your system back to a working state, be that `/etc/fstab` or `/etc/syslog.conf`.  You may need to manually mount filesystems that have not yet been mounted.